# Best eGPU to use with MacbookPro 15" 2018

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, gpu, osx

I'm using `Blender 2.9` on my Macbook Pro, but it renders very slowly in `Cycles on CPU`. I've tried using ProRender but it makes the interface very laggy and it doesn't render any faster (at least nothing noticeable).

When rendering I know to set all the settings properly for faster render (samples, tile size etc.), but I would like to render my art and animations on proper GPU.

These are my computer details.
[image]

What would be a proper eGPU to use with my computer? I realize this could be more opinion based question, but there are so many options out there that I am lost, also it gets expensive buying wrong gear.

Comment: Hadn't a chance to test epgu's myself... but there are several bottlenecks, that's for sure. In order to get the most out of your card(s) I personally would recommend against egpu's and put them into a linux/windows box until metal api is supported.

Comment: Also, if you have some time I'd recommend try a linux distro on your macbook to see whether that will speed up things before throwing it into the trash can.

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)